# Serving React build with Express shows nothing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have this project structure:

- app

  - server.js
  - frontend

    - build

      - index.html

`build` directory is the result after `npm run build` in my React app (created with `create-react-app`). There are more files but I omit them for the example.

I want to serve the React app as static files, so in `server.js`, I have this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/build', 'index.html'));
});    
app.listen(9001);
```

I navigate to `http://localhost:9001` in my browser and there are no errors but the screen is blank. React app is not shown.

If I run the React app (from inside `frontend` directory) with `npm start`, it works properly (in default webpack port 3000).

This is the `build/index.html` file (pretty printed):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">

  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

  <title>React App</title><link href="/static/css/main.65027555.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.a4d4d402.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

If I navigate to `http://localhost:9001/static/js/main.a4d4d402.js`, I can see the javascript file.

Comment: Show `index.html` file. Make sure the path you put to import script in `index.html` is correct.

Comment: I can navigate to the script with my browser, so I guess it's imported correctly. I have posted index.html in the question.

Comment: ...and in your browser, you can see the contents of the `main.a4d4d402.js` file too ?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on the browser console?

Comment: omg, I found the error. There was an error in the bootstrap imports. I was closing a <script> tag. In my question looks well because I have pretty printed by hand and maybe I have corrected it somehow. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. There was an error in the bootstrap imports in `index.html`. I was closing a  tag twice. In my question looks well because I have pretty printed by hand and maybe I have corrected it somehow.